# Weirdly small caret in contentEditable when empty

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have weird problem with contenteditable. I made span `display:inline-block` an editable item by adding `contenteditable=true` to the attributes.

When I click on it the caret is as normal, when I type it's also ok. But when I use backspace to delete all input, the caret gets small to 2pixel height.

It happens in Firefox 21.0
in Chrome it looks fine.

[image: appearance]

Comment: Have you checked the zoom level of the browser? Sometimes it causes this kind of weird rendering.

Comment: Can you provide a example on jsfiddle?

Comment: i immediately tried to wipe away a speck of dust on my screen :)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your exact issue, but the rule is simple - you always have to have `<br>` inside editable element to avoid such issues.